# Can these two jQuery lines produce different results?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am cleaning up an old jQuery plugin of mine, and I found this code:

```
var foo = $some.find(theCriteria).andSelf().filter(theCriteria);
```

That seems dumb, like it would be equivalent to:

```
var foo = $some.andSelf().find(theCriteria);
```

I assume there's some reason I wrote the first version, but I can't think what it would be. Is the latter code functionally equivalent? Or am I missing some subtle interaction?

In the above:

- `$some` is a jQuery object consisting of one or more elements, which usually have child elements.
- `theCriteria` is a compound CSS selector string, e.g. `".bar, .jim, .jam"`.
- The `andSelf()` is there because `$some` may have selected a single root element that has one of the CSS classes applied, and if so I want to select it.

Comment: _And no, I don't have a test suite for this plugin that would let me discover if making the change is safe or not. That's one thing I'm trying to change._

Comment: Would actually `$some.andSelf()` do anything useful?

Comment: @zerkms No, probably not. Ah…I think that's the clue. I'll see if someone else wants to answer before I spoil the fun with what I've just realized.

Comment: So the second wouldn't include elements from `$some` that match `theCriteria` selector. That's the difference I can think of. What the first does - joins 2 sets - the `$some` and all its ascendants and filters them by `theCriteria` selector.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Good question. This code has been around since 2008, but I don't remember when I ported it to jQuery. In this case I only care about latest (2.1.0+), so if the behavior is different now than it used to be, that's fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there's a difference:

```
<div id="test" class="bar">
  <div class="bar" />
</div>
```

With these expressions:

```
// gives both <div>
$('#test')
   .find('.bar')
   .andSelf()
   .filter('.bar');

// only returns the inner <div>
$('#test')
   .andSelf()
   .find('.bar')
```

This is because `filter()` operates on all items in the result set, whereas `find()` performs a DOM search on each node inside the result set, effectively skipping them.

Besides [`.addBack(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/addback/) you could do something like this:

```
$('#test')
   .find('.bar')
   .add($('#test').filter('.bar'))
```

Comment: I'm giving you the accept for the clear illustration of the difference. If any future reader has a similar situation, please see @Arun's answer for a more elegant way to achieve the same goal (and upvote his answer if you use it).

Comment: @Phrogz Thanks :) I've added a workaround for older versions as well.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not equivalent

If you want to support only jQuery 1.8+ then you can use .addBack() - [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Qa87f/3/)

```
var foo = $some.find(theCriteria).addBack(theCriteria);
```

else you can use .add

```
var foo = $some.find(theCriteria).add($some.filter(theCriteria));
```

It is not the same because of 2 reasons Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Qa87f/2/)

- andSelf() adds back the previous set of elements in your case there are not previous set of elements - this adds the document object to the element set causing undesired results
- since you are using .find(), you are not filtering the $some object set

Comment: You should probably elaborate on why it is different _(while I go read up on `addBack()` which I've not used before)_.

Comment: @Phrogz: the second wouldn't include anything from `$some`